# Pass sms body to default sms app

Tags: android, android-intent, sms

I found multiple threads here about this, but none of them are working for me. This is my code:

```
public void sendSMS (String number, String body) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("smsto:" + number));
        i.putExtra("abc", body);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

It opens stock SMS app and passes the number to send, but text body is empty.
I also tried this `Uri.fromParts(body, number, null)` but then the app just crashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your code with below code. You are not passing correct keys to detect number and text body for the sms.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:" + phoneNumber));     
intent.putExtra("sms_body", message); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Please read this documentation for detailed information. 
[Compose an SMS/MMS message with attachment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#Messaging)

Comment: Thank you, didn't realize that "sms_body" was a "constant" :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:" + phoneNumber));
            smsIntent.putExtra("address", "12125551212");
            smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body","Body of Message");
            startActivity(smsIntent);
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't realize that "sms_body" was a "constant" :)

Comment: @Nemanja "sma_body" is key  and its always constant for pass message into body